# Including a bundle in XCode 5

Tags: ios, xcode5

I am very new to iOS programming.

I am looking to use Google sign-in in my iOS app. I read through the google docs and have understood what needs to be done.

There is one sentence which I do not understand how to do -

If you plan to use the sign-in button provided by the SDK, include the GooglePlus.bundle in your XCode project to add it to your target.

I do not know how to include a bundle into the Xcode project and add it to the target. I googled but could not find an answer.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Just drag it into the Xcode sidebar panel where your project files are and do what @BlackRider said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the bundle file to your project, as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Adding_an_Existing_File_or_Folder.html).

You'll see the following dialog:

[image]

Here you'll need to do 2 things:

1. check the checkbox for "Copy items into destination group's
   folder."
2. check the checkboxes next to the names of projects where
   you'll be using the Goolge SDK.
3. click "Add"